# Struts2: Malformed OGNL expression

Tags: jquery, jsp, jakarta-ee, struts2, ognl

In my JSPs, I'm using a plugin named [TagEdit](http://tagedit.webwork-albrecht.de/), It has to have an input text field with " name='tag[]' " like below:

```
<s:form theme="simple" action="myActionn" method="post">
    <s:textfield theme="simple" name="tag[]" value="" cssClass="tag"/>
    <sj:submit targets="actionMessageResult"/>
</s:form>
```

But when I submit it, struts2 throws this exception:

```
WARNING: Error setting expression 'tag[]' with value '[Ljava.lang.String;@6c2a78'
ognl.ExpressionSyntaxException: Malformed OGNL expression: tag[] [ognl.ParseException: Encountered " "]" "] "" at line 1, column 5.
Was expecting one of:
    ":" ...
    "not" ...
    "+" ...
    "-" ...
    "~" ...
    "!" ...
    "(" ...
    "true" ...
    "false" ...
    "null" ...
    "#this" ...
    "#root" ...
    "#" ...
    "[" ...
    "{" ...
    "@" ...
    "new" ...
    <IDENT> ...
    <DYNAMIC_SUBSCRIPT> ...
    "\'" ...
    "`" ...
    "\"" ...
    <INT_LITERAL> ...
    <FLT_LITERAL> ...
    ]
    at ognl.Ognl.parseExpression(Ognl.java:112)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlUtil.compile(OgnlUtil.java:225)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlUtil.setValue(OgnlUtil.java:209)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlValueStack.trySetValue(OgnlValueStack.java:173)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlValueStack.setValue(OgnlValueStack.java:160)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlValueStack.setValue(OgnlValueStack.java:151)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.setParameters(ParametersInterceptor.java:292)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:203)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:211)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:190)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.MultiselectInterceptor.intercept(MultiselectInterceptor.java:75)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:90)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:243)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:100)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:141)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:145)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:171)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:176)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:192)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:187)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:54)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:510)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher.doFilter(FilterDispatcher.java:434)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:852)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: ognl.ParseException: Encountered " "]" "] "" at line 1, column 5.
Was expecting one of:
    ":" ...
    "not" ...
    "+" ...
    "-" ...
    "~" ...
    "!" ...
    "(" ...
    "true" ...
    "false" ...
    "null" ...
    "#this" ...
    "#root" ...
    "#" ...
    "[" ...
    "{" ...
    "@" ...
    "new" ...
    <IDENT> ...
    <DYNAMIC_SUBSCRIPT> ...
    "\'" ...
    "`" ...
    "\"" ...
    <INT_LITERAL> ...
    <FLT_LITERAL> ...

    at ognl.OgnlParser.generateParseException(OgnlParser.java:3172)
    at ognl.OgnlParser.jj_consume_token(OgnlParser.java:3051)
    at ognl.OgnlParser.unaryExpression(OgnlParser.java:1236)
    at ognl.OgnlParser.multiplicativeExpression(OgnlParser.java:971)
    at ognl.OgnlParser.additiveExpression(OgnlParser.java:894)
    at ognl.OgnlParser.shiftExpression(OgnlParser.java:750)
    at ognl.OgnlParser.relationalExpression(OgnlParser.java:508)
    at ognl.OgnlParser.equalityExpression(OgnlParser.java:405)
    at ognl.OgnlParser.andExpression(OgnlParser.java:352)
    at ognl.OgnlParser.exclusiveOrExpression(OgnlParser.java:299)
    at ognl.OgnlParser.inclusiveOrExpression(OgnlParser.java:246)
    at ognl.OgnlParser.logicalAndExpression(OgnlParser.java:193)
    at ognl.OgnlParser.logicalOrExpression(OgnlParser.java:140)
    at ognl.OgnlParser.conditionalTestExpression(OgnlParser.java:101)
    at ognl.OgnlParser.assignmentExpression(OgnlParser.java:64)
    at ognl.OgnlParser.expression(OgnlParser.java:23)
    at ognl.OgnlParser.index(OgnlParser.java:2336)
    at ognl.OgnlParser.navigationChain(OgnlParser.java:1331)
    at ognl.OgnlParser.unaryExpression(OgnlParser.java:1196)
    at ognl.OgnlParser.multiplicativeExpression(OgnlParser.java:971)
    at ognl.OgnlParser.additiveExpression(OgnlParser.java:894)
    at ognl.OgnlParser.shiftExpression(OgnlParser.java:750)
    at ognl.OgnlParser.relationalExpression(OgnlParser.java:508)
    at ognl.OgnlParser.equalityExpression(OgnlParser.java:405)
    at ognl.OgnlParser.andExpression(OgnlParser.java:352)
    at ognl.OgnlParser.exclusiveOrExpression(OgnlParser.java:299)
    at ognl.OgnlParser.inclusiveOrExpression(OgnlParser.java:246)
    at ognl.OgnlParser.logicalAndExpression(OgnlParser.java:193)
    at ognl.OgnlParser.logicalOrExpression(OgnlParser.java:140)
    at ognl.OgnlParser.conditionalTestExpression(OgnlParser.java:101)
    at ognl.OgnlParser.assignmentExpression(OgnlParser.java:64)
    at ognl.OgnlParser.expression(OgnlParser.java:23)
    at ognl.OgnlParser.topLevelExpression(OgnlParser.java:15)
    at ognl.Ognl.parseExpression(Ognl.java:110)
    ... 52 more
/-- Encapsulated exception ------------\
ognl.ParseException: Encountered " "]" "] "" at line 1, column 5.
Was expecting one of:
    ":" ...
    "not" ...
    "+" ...
    "-" ...
    "~" ...
    "!" ...
    "(" ...
    "true" ...
    "false" ...
    "null" ...
    "#this" ...
    "#root" ...
    "#" ...
    "[" ...
    "{" ...
    "@" ...
    "new" ...
    <IDENT> ...
    <DYNAMIC_SUBSCRIPT> ...
    "\'" ...
    "`" ...
    "\"" ...
    <INT_LITERAL> ...
    <FLT_LITERAL> ...

    at ognl.OgnlParser.generateParseException(OgnlParser.java:3172)
    at ognl.OgnlParser.jj_consume_token(OgnlParser.java:3051)
    at ognl.OgnlParser.unaryExpression(OgnlParser.java:1236)
    at ognl.OgnlParser.multiplicativeExpression(OgnlParser.java:971)
    at ognl.OgnlParser.additiveExpression(OgnlParser.java:894)
    at ognl.OgnlParser.shiftExpression(OgnlParser.java:750)
    at ognl.OgnlParser.relationalExpression(OgnlParser.java:508)
    at ognl.OgnlParser.equalityExpression(OgnlParser.java:405)
    at ognl.OgnlParser.andExpression(OgnlParser.java:352)
    at ognl.OgnlParser.exclusiveOrExpression(OgnlParser.java:299)
    at ognl.OgnlParser.inclusiveOrExpression(OgnlParser.java:246)
    at ognl.OgnlParser.logicalAndExpression(OgnlParser.java:193)
    at ognl.OgnlParser.logicalOrExpression(OgnlParser.java:140)
    at ognl.OgnlParser.conditionalTestExpression(OgnlParser.java:101)
    at ognl.OgnlParser.assignmentExpression(OgnlParser.java:64)
    at ognl.OgnlParser.expression(OgnlParser.java:23)
    at ognl.OgnlParser.index(OgnlParser.java:2336)
    at ognl.OgnlParser.navigationChain(OgnlParser.java:1331)
    at ognl.OgnlParser.unaryExpression(OgnlParser.java:1196)
    at ognl.OgnlParser.multiplicativeExpression(OgnlParser.java:971)
    at ognl.OgnlParser.additiveExpression(OgnlParser.java:894)
    at ognl.OgnlParser.shiftExpression(OgnlParser.java:750)
    at ognl.OgnlParser.relationalExpression(OgnlParser.java:508)
    at ognl.OgnlParser.equalityExpression(OgnlParser.java:405)
    at ognl.OgnlParser.andExpression(OgnlParser.java:352)
    at ognl.OgnlParser.exclusiveOrExpression(OgnlParser.java:299)
    at ognl.OgnlParser.inclusiveOrExpression(OgnlParser.java:246)
    at ognl.OgnlParser.logicalAndExpression(OgnlParser.java:193)
    at ognl.OgnlParser.logicalOrExpression(OgnlParser.java:140)
    at ognl.OgnlParser.conditionalTestExpression(OgnlParser.java:101)
    at ognl.OgnlParser.assignmentExpression(OgnlParser.java:64)
    at ognl.OgnlParser.expression(OgnlParser.java:23)
    at ognl.OgnlParser.topLevelExpression(OgnlParser.java:15)
    at ognl.Ognl.parseExpression(Ognl.java:110)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlUtil.compile(OgnlUtil.java:225)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlUtil.setValue(OgnlUtil.java:209)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlValueStack.trySetValue(OgnlValueStack.java:173)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlValueStack.setValue(OgnlValueStack.java:160)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlValueStack.setValue(OgnlValueStack.java:151)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.setParameters(ParametersInterceptor.java:292)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:203)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:211)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:190)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.MultiselectInterceptor.intercept(MultiselectInterceptor.java:75)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:90)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:243)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:100)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:141)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:145)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:171)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:176)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:192)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:187)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:54)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:510)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher.doFilter(FilterDispatcher.java:434)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:852)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
\--------------------------------------/
```

The struts.xml:

```
    <package name="default" extends="struts-default" >
        <interceptors>
            <interceptor-stack name="defaultStack">
                <interceptor-ref name="params">
                    <param name="excludeParams">^tag\..*</param>
                </interceptor-ref>
            </interceptor-stack>
        </interceptors>

        <action name="myActionn" class="com.fap.controller.common.tagAction">
            <result name="success">ajax_result/common/actionMessage/action_message_result_error.jsp</result>
            <result name="error">ajax_result/common/actionMessage/action_message_result_error.jsp</result>
        </action>

    </package>
```

And the action:

```
public class tagAction extends ActionSupport {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public String execute() {
        try {
            Map params = (Map) ActionContext.getContext().getParameters();

            String[] entries1 = (String[]) params.get("tag[3-a]");
            String[] entries2 = (String[]) params.get("tag[]");
            for(int i=0;i<entries1.length;i++)
                System.out.println(entries1[i]);
            for(int i=0;i<entries2.length;i++)
                System.out.println(entries2[i]);


        } catch (Exception e) {
            addActionError(e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "error";
        }
        return "success";
    }
}
```

what should I do buddies?
thank you all

Comment: Just to make life a bit easier, can you provide the action as well so we can see what you are trying to set in the action with <s:textfield theme="simple" name="tag[]" value="" cssClass="tag"/>, if you don't intend to submit the value to the action then you'll need to use some JS to disable the form element or if you do intend to send a single value change the text field name the proper name (probably drop the []) before it makes its way to the action... again with JS.

Comment: i am with Quaternion,show your action code else it will be a guess work for others

Comment: @Quaternion : sorry, I updated the question ;)

Comment: @AminSh: i am wondering why the text field name is `tag[]`, any reason for that? more over you can create simple property in your action class with getter and setters, no need to play with `ActionContext`, S2 provide a clean way to transfer values to your action

Comment: @UmeshAwasthi : I know that, but the plugin wants that!!! I cant rename the input field!!!!!

Comment: @AminSh: this is because `tag[]` is being treated by OGNL as array and which is not the case in actual.One quick solution is to use alias interceptor like `<param name="aliases">#{ 'tag[]' : 'tag' }</param>`

Comment: @Umesh that's interesting... but wouldn't it be pretty easy for him to just remove the "[]" with jQuery before the values are submitted, when the submit button is clicked... I've done such handling to modify form parameters before sending so it is definitely possible.  Really its 50/50 you can handle this on the struts2 side... or on the client side. I would argue the client side is the one with the weird convention so it would probably be best to handle it there.

Comment: I'm adding the jQuery tag perhaps we'll see a nice JS/jQuery answer.

Comment: For someone providing a JS/jQuery solution they will not know how the jsp will render as html so posting the html would be good.

Comment: @Quaternion +1 i never though about this option,sorry not so good at jS/Jquery side :)